# Delete a column that has all Nan's in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```
 x = pd.DataFrame({'x':[np.nan, 22, 11, np.nan, np.nan],
                   'letters':['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
                   'Nan1': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                   'bools': [True, True, False, True, False],
                   'Nan2': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                   'y': [100,200,11,333, 70]})
```

I'd like to learn the best way to delete all columns from this DataFrame who have all NaNs. In this case, it would delete columns Nan1 and Nan2.

I have a feeling there's a good way to do this!

Answer (score 10):

AFAIK [DataFrame.dropna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) is the most idiomatic way to do that:

```
In [17]: x = x.dropna(how='all', axis=1)

In [18]: x
Out[18]:
   bools letters     x    y
0   True       a   NaN  100
1   True       a  22.0  200
2  False       b  11.0   11
3   True       b   NaN  333
4  False       b   NaN   70
```

Comment: Ok , let me turn it to an answer : -)

Comment: @Wen, sure!  :-)

Answer (score 2):

Using `dropna` with `thresh` *(thresh : int, default None
int value : require that many **non-NA** values)*

```
x.dropna(1,thresh=1)
Out[721]: 
   bools letters     x    y
0   True       a   NaN  100
1   True       a  22.0  200
2  False       b  11.0   11
3   True       b   NaN  333
4  False       b   NaN   70
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `loc`:

```
x.loc[:, ~x.isnull().all()]
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
x.dropna(axis=1, how='all', inplace=True)
```